# Only repel nodes of different group

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to group nodes in D3 in such way that nodes within the same group do not repel each other, but the do repel nodes from another group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are talking about the force layout. You can't do what you want directly, but you can do it with several force layouts. For each pair of nodes from different groups, you would need to create a seperate force layout that causes them to repel each other.

You would end up with a quadratic number of force layouts, but unless you're planning on having many nodes (or more groups) it shouldn't be a problem performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about grouping of nodes you can have a look [here](http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/). A very nice example by JIM VALLANDINGHAM.